# do not swipe out the notifcation message from notification bar on firebase on background using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using xamarin forms for app development. I am using firebase push notification for my app and using the following code for receiving notification. When my app is on foreground, the notification should not be swiped out, but when app is background we can swipe the notification. Please see the below code what i am using:

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            try
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
                Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
                SendNotifications(message);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Logs.LogCreate("OnMessageReceived Exception" + ex.Message);
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            }
        }

        public void SendNotifications(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            try
            {
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);

                var seed = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"\d+").Value);
                int id = new Random(seed).Next(000000000, 999999999);

                var push = new Intent();

                var fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0,
                        push, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

                NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
                {
                    var chan1 = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL,
                       new Java.Lang.String("Primary"), NotificationImportance.High);
                    chan1.LightColor = Color.Green;

                    manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);

                    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL).SetOngoing(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                }

                notification.SetContentIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent)
                         .SetContentTitle(message.GetNotification().Title)
                         .SetContentText(message.GetNotification().Body)
                         .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon))
                         .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_transparent)
                         .SetStyle((new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()))
                         .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh)
                         .SetColor(0x9c6114)
                         .SetAutoCancel(true)
                         .SetOngoing(true);

                manager.Notify(id, notification.Build());

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Please give me suggestions for this.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, but your code of this(`var name = message.Data["key1"];`)    is extremely error-prone.

Comment: Thank you for your reply JessieZhang-MSFT. I removed that code. But it is not working on background.

Comment: You can try to use:`.SetAutoCancel(false).SetOngoing(true);`

Comment: I try this also. It is not working.The following override method is calling background also:```public override void HandleIntent(Intent p0)
        {
                base.HandleIntent(p0);
                    CreateNotification(p0);
        }```

Comment: Sorry so late to reply, have you resolved this qustion?

Comment: Thank you for reply Jessie. I already mentioned that i am using the following:.The following override method is calling background also:public override void HandleIntent(Intent p0) { base.HandleIntent(p0); CreateNotification(p0); }